# Scikit learn Decision Tree not deterministic

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, cart

I am doing recursive feature elimination and cross-validated selection (RFECV) in order to get the best number of features. As I will be comparing different hyper-parameters and methods in dealing with unbalanced data at a later stage I would like the best features to be deterministic. Therefore I have used a decision tree.

However, every time I run the code below I get a different no. of best features. I have used a constant random state throughout and cannot understand why the results differ between runs?

````
RANDOM_ST = 123

def featureSelection(train, train_labels):

    # Decision tree for feature selection
    estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=RANDOM_ST)

    # Custom cv so I can seed with random state => results are comparable between different options later
    rskv = model_selection.RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=1, random_state=RANDOM_ST)

    # Greedy Feature Selection
    rfecv= RFECV(estimator, cv=rskv, n_jobs=-1)
    rfecv.fit(train, train_labels)

    # optimal number of features
    print('Optimal no. of features is: ', rfecv.n_features_)

    # drop the un-informative features
    train = train.iloc[:, rfecv.support_]


    return train, train_labels
```
````

Comment: Is the `KNN` part relevant to the question? If not, please edit it out, in order to create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @ItamarMushkin `KNN` part was used for testing so not directly relevant. I've removed it now

Comment: Good! Can you also provide some minimal dataset that reproduces the problem? (I can't find it by simple inspection)

Comment: This needs a reproducible example to be answerable.